# Помощь с python 3.6.1 list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, коллекции

```
s = input().lower().split()
print (s[0])
d = {}
for i in s:
  for g in range (s[0] , s[i]):
    if i == g:
      d[i] = []
      d[i] += 1
print (d)
```

Пытаюсь сделать счетчик слов, чтобы повторяющиеся слова из вводимой строки добавлялись в словарь с key = Повторяющееся слово и value = кол во повторений. Всё время выдает ошибку :

```
 File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    for g in range (s[0] , s[i]):
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Помогите пожалуйста)

Comment: Код странный. Какой условие задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по тому, что делает ваш код - вы пытаетесь переизобрести [collections.Counter()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

s = ['a', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'd', 'c']

d = Counter(s)
```

Результат:

```
In [214]: d
Out[214]: Counter({'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1})
```

к объекту `collections.Counter` можно обращаться как к словарю:

```
In [222]: d['a']
Out[222]: 4
```

два наиболее часто встречающихся элемента:

```
In [215]: d.most_common(2)
Out[215]: [('a', 4), ('b', 2)]
```

в виде словаря:

```
In [216]: dict(d)
Out[216]: {'a': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 2, 'd': 1}
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что индексация в списках может быть только по целым числам.

---

Давайте разберем код:

```
s = input().lower().split()     # Тут получается список строк
...

for i in s:                     # Тут в цикле перебираете элементы списка (элемент списка это строка)
  for g in range (s[0] , s[i]): # В s[i] и происходит ошибка
...
```

---

Повтор ошибки:

```
s = ['a', 'b', 'c']
print(s[0])  # OK
print(s[1])  # OK
print(s['2'])  # FAIL
print(s['a'])  # FAIL

for i in s:
    print(s[i])  # FAIL
```

---

**PS.** Предположу, что вам нужно было пройтись по индексам вашего списка, тогда ваш цикл изменится на: `for i in range(len(s)):` или `for i, item in enumerate(s):`

Comment: Спасибо! Немного исправил код. Теперь все ок.
s = input().lower().split()
d = {}
for i in s:
  if s.count(i) >= 1:
    d[i] = 0
    d[i] = s.count (i)
for h in d:
  print ( h, d[h])

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Немного исправил код. Теперь все ок)

```
s = input().lower().split()
d = {}
for i in s:
   if s.count(i) >= 1:
   d[i] = 0
   d[i] = s.count (i)
for h in d:
print ( h, d[h])
```